# How to convert string to decimal in this list of lists?

Tags: python, list, decimal, string-conversion

I'm trying to convert the strings in this list of lists into decimal form:

`ask = [['31188.28758860', 2], ['31183.48445986', 0.14258435], ...]`

I tried using `elem.strip('"') for elem in ask` to remove the quote marks but get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'" So I assume I am not accessing the nested level of the strings

Comment: what is the output you expect?

Comment: when you do `for elem in ask`, `elem` is a list and using `strip` on the list gives you the error.

Comment: `elem` is a list, not a string. To get the string you need `elem[0]`. But you can't convert a string to a float by "removing the quotes". What you see is the source code representation of the string. It doesn't have quotes internally in memory. Instead there is a complex data structure that says it is a string of length 13. And internally a float looks even less like its source code representation. Convert the string using a call to ` float()`, not by trying to manipulate externalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[float(elem[0]) for elem in ask]
```

to just get the first values of your nested list.

OR

```
[[float(elem[0]), elem[1]] for elem in ask]
```

to get the same structure than before, but with the strings replaced by floats.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ans = [[float(i) if type(i)==str else i  for i in j] for j in ask]
print(ans)
```

### The Output

```
[[31188.2875886, 2], [31183.48445986, 0.14258435]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ask = [['31188.28758860', 2], ['31183.48445986', 0.14258435], ...]

converted_ask = [[float(x[0]), x[1]] for x in ask]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, you would help OP and future readers more by explaining *why* and *how* your code solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
ask = [['31188.28758860', 2], ['31183.48445986', 0.14258435]]
ask_list = [[float(j) for j in i] for i in ask]
```

This will do your work. The output (ask_list) will be `[[31188.2875886, 2.0], [31183.48445986, 0.14258435]]`.